# "RCTBundleURLProvider.h" file not found - AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to run my React Native app in XCode and I keep getting this error. I cannot figure out how to resolve the issue. Any suggestions?

Screen Shot of Error in XCode:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I would suggest before applying any changes just clean your project and try to run it because same thing happen in my case. I just clean my project and run it and it works.

Comment: You should definitely change the right answer! @mark 's answer is the right one and everyone comes for it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Delete node modules, then run `npm install` (or better yet yarn) and after everything has finished downloading, run `react-native upgrade` which should give you the option to replace old files with the template ones, by doing so you re-link your native dependencies in react-native which should fix your problem. Of course don't forget to clean your project in Xcode.

Comment: You can use the new upgrade tool based on Git as it resolved conflicts automatically. Run "npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade" followed by "react-native-git-upgrade".

Comment: I followed suggestions but nogo.. i have react-native version 0.41.2 is there anybody who is able to fix this on version 0.41.2? thanks.

Comment: this also did not work for me. using xcode 8.2.1 and react native 0.41.2

Comment: I tried this, and it blew away some important project settings.  I'm building an Action Extension, and after running `react-native upgrade` all my build settings were deleted.

Comment: @ShaneOSullivan use git to avoid those kind of problems. :)

Comment: i would add 'delete the yarn.lock' file so you can use 'npm install'

Comment: works for me.  You probably forgot to close your React Packager (terminal) which is running with a different version of react native. Try to close it and restart your app again. Thanks

Comment: @SalehMasum This is what happened to me. Gotta make sure all processes connected to app are closed

Answer (score 249):

xcode Product->Scheme->Manage Schemes click '+'  at the Target to select "React" and set the React is shared.

Comment: I hit '+' and there is no "React" to select.  A dialog comes up with "Target: MyApp" and Name: MyApp."   Nothing says React or shared.

Comment: This happened to me after installing cocopods which created an xcworkspace file. My existing xcodeproj did not have "React" as an option but the xcworkspace did.

Comment: @PeteAlvin i ran Run "npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade followed by "react-native-git-upgrade" and then it showed the react option for me

Comment: After I did that Build Succeeded, but Run is not active in Xcode after that

Comment: Thanks a ton. I wonder why this is not the accepted solution.

Answer (score 19):

For all those are using **React Native 0.40.0** or higher, Header Imports have a major change from **RN 0.40.0** and result in lots of .h file not found errors. `react-native-git-upgrade` fixed the issue for me while in debug but build fails in release/archive.

I am using **RN 0.42.3** with cocoapods and **Xcode 8.2.1**

To completely fix this go to Xcode>Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme>

1. Untick **Parallelize Build**
   [image]
2. Click on + button in Targets and add **React**
   [image]
3. Drag the added **React** to top of the List in Targets.
   [image]

Now clean the project and build

Comment: This did not fix for me, react v.0.44.0

Answer (score 17):

None of the other suggestions were fixing my error but this one did it.

## 1 - Create Podfile

Create a file named `ios/Podfile` inside your react-native app with the following contents:

```
# You Podfile should look similar to this file. React Native currently does not support use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

target '<YOUR_APP_NAME>' do
  # Fixes required for pod specs to work with rn 0.42
  react_native_path = "../node_modules/react-native"
  pod "Yoga", :path => "#{react_native_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod "React", :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]

  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # <~~ remove this line if you do not want to support GoogleMaps on iOS

# when not using frameworks  we can do this instead of including the source files in our project (1/4):
#  pod 'react-native-maps', path: '../../'
#  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: '../../'  # <~~ if you need GoogleMaps support on iOS
end
```

## 2 - Install Podfile

Run the command `pod install` from inside the ios folder.

## 3 - Reset XCode

Restart XCode and the error should be gone.

Comment: This solves the issue to some extent. But what I found out was that new configurations do not seem to respect the build order so they are not taking custom scripts in. Fundamentally this is an issue with react-native or react-native + xcode

Answer (score 9):

The solution that works for me is to share `React` scheme.

If you don't have React scheme, create new one by `Selecting scheme menu -> Manage Scheme -> + -> choose React`, then mark React scheme as Shared

[image]

[image]
[image]

Also, if you use Xcode 10, go to `File -> Project Settings` and select Legacy build system

[image]

Comment: thank you! It's hard sometimes to fix these kind of problems without having knowledge of iOS and Android native development I think and the tools that are used with.

Comment: @onmyway133 I wish I can up-vote  your answer more ! Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem after my first try running a React build in XCode, and all I had to do was actually build and run to make the error go away (after picking a team and proper provisioning).  Sometimes XCode shows errors that aren't really errors until it compiles and links things the first time.

Comment: Me too. It's strange, just build and debug, the errors disappeared. I don't know why.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald - A license to what?  I don't believe I needed to license anything...

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by following steps:

1. In xcode choose project root.
2. Drag `React.xcodeproj` from `Libraries` to the root of the project.
3. Click on project name (in my case it name `SaleKit`) in `TARGETS`
4. Choose `Build Phases`
5. In dropdown of `Target Dependencies` add `React`
6. Rebuild or re-run

[image]

Comment: This worked for me! I use react-native-schemes-manager, and so it was my Staging scheme that wouldn't build until I added this. It worked previously for months, then suddenly didn't after a fresh clone. Suspect my NPM ranges in package.json are too generous.

Comment: Worked for me, without the need to drag React.xcodeproj out of Libraries folder.

Comment: Any ideas if there is no dependency `react` listed?

Answer (score 6):

For my case in ReactNative "0.54.2", i solved it with following solution

In Xcode select `Product->Scheme->Manage Schemes`, untick 'YourProject'-tvOS set it to not Shared

Comment: Its works for me, react-native verison :  0.55.4. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me! I have deleted tvOS target before and forgot to remove it as scheme! => RN 0.56

Answer (score 5):

Best Solution :

Open 'Build Settings' for your project in Xcode , search 'Header Search Path'.

Double click next to 'Header Search Path', where other properties have a 'yes' or 'no'

Now add following to the "Header Search Path" (under Build Settings):

```
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React/Base
```

Don`t forget Make both of them recursive.

Answer (score 4):

You might be running `.xcodeproj` file after pod is installed.

Close it and open `.xcworkspace` file. It worked for me.

Comment: i love you this worked, and made my facepalm irl

Answer (score 2):

In the base dir of the project I run:

`node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache`

Which resulted in:

```
Scanning 554 folders for symlinks in /Users/..../work/..../react_tutorial/AwesomeProject/node_modules (15ms)
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │
 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │
 │  prefer.                                                                   │
 │                                                                            │
 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │
 │                                                                            │
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/..../work/...../react_tutorial/AwesomeProject

Loading dependency graph... ERROR  Packager can't listen on port 8081
Most likely another process is already using this port
Run the following command to find out which process:

lsof -i :8081
```

I found that package manager can't run when another packager process is running.

I found the process running with:

`lsof -i :8081`

Than I `kill 9 ...` the process.

After than I closed Xcode, run:

`npm install`

And started Xcode again, from this moment everything work as expected!!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Clean (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).
2. Build core React - select React as the scheme in Xcode and build it (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).
3. Build the library that is failing (e.g. RCTText).
4. Build your app.

Comment: How do you build a library exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by placing **RNFIRMessaging.h** above the **React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h**

So it look I will look like:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNFIRMessaging.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

click Product->Scheme->Manage Schemes->+ . and then add react as shared. also insure that your project name is there too.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue .then i have deleted node .try to use these steps

1. Delete the node_modules folder - rm -rf node_modules && npm install
2. Reset packager cache - rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-* or
   node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache
3. Clear watchman watches - watchman watch-del-all

then make build and see

Comment: yup i also tried this on react-native version 0.41.2 still not working as well... any inputs? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my fix to this issue after upgrading React was to change the declaration of `#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"` to `#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install` in your project directory to install `react-native` resolving this error.

Answer (score 1):

For me replacing

```
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
```

by

```
#import <RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <RCTRootView.h>
```

in AppDelegate.m file worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent run `npm install` you are likely to encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through all the answers mentioned above.

Here is the solution worked for me:

**STEP 1:**

Run:

```
npm install react-native-fcm --save
```

This result in making the directory in your project under **node_modules > react-native-fcm**

[image: Add react-native-fcm to your project]

**STEP 2:**

You need to add `'$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-fcm/ios'` to
 header search paths in build settings.

[image: Add to header search paths]

These 2 steps worked for me to remove the error.

For more details you can go through these links:

https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/63

https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I couldn't delete node_modules and re-install and I also couldn't do `react-native-git-updgrade` or `react-native upgrade` because I wanted to stay on RN-0.59 because .60 causes problems for my dependencies.

Anyway my situation was that I was missing 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file. I already had React available in my schemas. It was not in my libraries directory. I checked my *target*'s build settings.

Inside target dependencies, I also had React in there.

**I deleted 'React' target dependency, then re-added. cleaned build folders, re-built project. it worked.**

Comment: Not sure it matters, but there's a typo in: react-native-git-updgrade

Answer (score 0):

I am using React Native 0.61. I created a Share Extension and was getting this error. I needed to replace:

```
#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
```

with

```
#import "React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.63.3/template/ios/Podfile

Find/Replace `HelloWorld` with your your project name.

Place this file into the `./ios` folder in your project

```
gem install cocoapods
cd ios
pod install
```

Then open the `YourProject.xcworkspace` file in XCode

in XCode, go to `Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes` and check `React`

Then try building the project again.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the suggestions and none of them worked at the i deleted the repo and clone it again and that work for me, so my suggestion is commit your changes back them up and clone the repo again that worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

you need to install react native,
in terminal run

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then

```
brew install node
brew install watchman
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

source:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: It's not an answer for this question

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that the path to your project don't have any spaces.
Just renaming folders and deleting spaces solves the problem for me.