# React Native 0.40.0 : RCTBundleURLProvider.h” file not found - AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, react-native

I am getting following error with react native version 0.40.0 version  React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found.

I tried deleting node modules , installing it with npm install and clearing watchman.multiple times. But still not able to get it working.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368211/rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m/43007066#43007066

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of React Native 0.40 (see [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.40.0)), native code on iOS must refer to headers out of the react namespace. Previously the following would work:

```
#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
```

But now all headers have been moved:

```
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
```

If you are updating an existing project, you need to either

- run `react-native upgrade` and merge these changes manually,
- use the new [react-native-git-upgrade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-git-upgrade) tool, or
- manually change all header imports to the new format.

Comment: Yup tried this on react-native version 0.41.2 no luck... any inputs anyone? thanks

Answer (score 5):

Got it working by dropping the default target on XCode and recreating it again.

Also, make sure to check `Manage Schemes` > [select your main target] > `Edit` > `Build`  tab.

[image: Xcode Schemes]

Check that `React` is in the list, and mark the scheme as `Shared`. Otherwise, it will be saved in your user's folder and GIT will ignore it.

Hope it helps, official docs didn't help

Comment: yup on react-native version 0.41.2 scheme is already configured this way.. but no luck it still won't get rid of this issue. any suggestions guys? thanks