# <RCTBridgeModule.h> can't be found for iOS Build

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, svn, react-native

[Failed to find rctbridgemodule.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k3t0.png)

Hey guys,
i got this issue with xcode for my react-native project. 
My coworker updated our project to a new revision and updated react-native itself how he said. After that the IOS Build doesn't work like it used to.

Android is all set, everything works just as beautiful as before.

I tried to solve it with this solution:
https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-svgkit/issues/11

but it didn't work for me.

Just deleted and installed the node_modules a couple of times and reinstalled it using `npm i` and `npm install`.

But no success.

Would be a blessing if you could help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native 0.40.0 : RCTBundleURLProvider.h” file not found - AppDelegate.m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704534/react-native-0-40-0-rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m)

Comment: @adamwebspace see my answer in the linked question above

Comment: thanks for your answer @jevkallio i did as you wrote but didn't help me. goddamit

Comment: Have a try on my solution to a similar question that was posted previously, [React Native / Xcode Upgrade and now RCTConvert.h not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477241/react-native-xcode-upgrade-and-now-rctconvert-h-not-found/41488258#41488258).

Comment: @max23_ thanks for your comment man, but unfortunately it didn't work