# React Native XcodeBuild fails on header import in CI

Tags: reactjs, react-native, xcodebuild, circleci

I am attempting to build a React Native application on an Os X CircleCI box.

My circle.yml is as follows:

```
machine:
  xcode:
    version: 8.3.3
  environment:
    PATH: '$PATH:$HOME/node/node-v4.4.3-darwin-x64/bin'

dependencies:
  pre:
    - brew install node
    - npm install -g react-native-cli
    - npm install
    - react-native link

test:
  override:
    - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -project 'ios/myApp.xcodeproj' -scheme 'myApp' clean build test -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=9.0,name=iPhone 6' CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= PROVISIONING_PROFILE= | tee $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/xcode_raw.log | xcpretty --color --report junit --output $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/xcode/results.xml
```

Which fails with:

```
  /Users/distiller/my-app/ios/myApp/AppDelegate.m:12:9: 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found

 #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
```

My package.json is follows:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-watch": "jest --watch",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/circle": "^4.5.2",
    "@turf/envelope": "^4.5.2",
    "@turf/helpers": "^4.5.2",
    "gl-react-native": "^2.42.3",
    "react": "~15.4.0-rc.4",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.39.2",
    "react-native-config": "0.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^1.5.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "__coverage__",
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "./node_modules/enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base|react-navigation|react-native-fabric)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./test-setup.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

By running a build with ssh enabled and inspecting the version, I can say that react-native-cli is installed at 2.0.1

Interestingly, this behaviour does not exhibit when the project is built (with the exact same command) on my machine (localhost)

By googling, I have found things like: [React Native 0.40.0 : RCTBundleURLProvider.h” file not found - AppDelegate.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704534/react-native-0-40-0-rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m)

Describing my problem exactly, however they are all limited to RN 4.0, while my package.json is explicitly pegged at 3.9.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution seemed to be to delete my `ios/build` directory. Once I did so, I started having the same behavior locally as in CircleCi (which I could then fix by simply taking `React` out of the import path like so:

```
#import <RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my test script wasn't running `yarn install`. So a fresh clone and build would fail. You could add something like this to your `config.yml` file:

```
  - run:
      name: Install React Native
      command: yarn install
```