# ReactNative 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found with react-native-fbsdk

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I installed react-native-fbsdk by fllowing instructions.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

However, I got the error in AppDelegate.m

'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h> <- Error here
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNFIRMessaging.h"
```

uninstalling react-native-fbsdk solves this issue so apparently this library causes the issue.
things I tried are

1. edit schema like this  [React Native 0.40.0 : RCTBundleURLProvider.h” file not found - AppDelegate.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704534/react-native-0-40-0-rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m)
2. install different version(0.5, 0.6, 0.6.1)
3. followed SnehaGindi's comment on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12077

all of them did not work.

My package.json is shown below. 
is there any clue?

```
{
  "name": "BitcoinApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.16.2",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "native-base": "2.1.5",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-base": "0.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-native-app-intro": "1.1.5",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^7.5.1",
    "react-native-firebase-analytics": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-gifted-form": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "0.5.0",
    "react-native-pathjs-charts": "0.0.29",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "0.6.6",
    "react-native-social-share": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-store": "0.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.2",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Uninstalled SDK and read followed instructions again.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

This time, in "Step 2: Download Facebook SDK for iOS", placed SDK in "~/Documents/FacebookSDK".

So, this issue caused because SDK directory is placed other than "~/Documents/FacebookSDK".