# Why does my xcode project build on simulator but not device in xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have a react native project that runs successfully on simulator but not on device.

[image]

I have run the project on the same device before, but not since I've incorporated cocoapods, though none of the above library are in cocoapods. I'm building in xcworkspace rather than a project file, not sure if that is it.

Not sure what this could be... Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Did you run 'pod install'? If not, open terminal, go to your project workspace and run 'pod install'. Clean & try again.

Comment: I ran pod install, all of the libraries were installed. The ones throwing errors were never in my podfile either.

Comment: I too had same issue with device and also with release scheme. Checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43007066/6423570

Answer (score 2):

Usually these type of errors appear when the libraries are not linked with the project.

The libraries might have been unlinked after adding cocoapods. Try running `npm install` and then `react-native link` to link all the libraries or run `react-native link <library-name>` to link the specific library in the terminal from your project root directory.