# What is proper way to use cocoapods with React Native (0.43.4) in ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have dug through a number of posts trying to set up a react native project using cocoapods for native ios libraries but I inevitably end up with an error for a missing file in `#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>` statement in my `AppDelegate.m` file.

What is the proper way to use cocoa pods with react-native? At the time of this post my current version of RN is 0.43.4 and I'm using Xcode 8.2.1.

This was my process, curious where I might be going wrong:

1) In the terminal, I create a new project using `react-native init TestProject`

2) I run `pod init` in the ios directory of that project

3) I add a dependency in my podFile and run `pod install`

4) The install process succeeds, but I see a warning that my targets `override the 'OTHER_LDFLAGS`' and it's suggested I use `$(inherit)` in my linker flags in Xcode.

5) So based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods) I add `$(inherited)` to *Project> TestProject > BuildSettings > linking> Other Linker Flags* which was otherwise empty. I also checked and saw that `$(inherited)` was already present in *Targets > TestProject> Build Settings> Linking> Other Linker Flags* and PreProcessor Macros as well.

6) At this point I see **React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h file not found** error on the `#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>` statement in `AppDelegate.m`

7) Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368211/rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m) I try deleting the `node modules` directory and back in the terminal run `npm install` and when complete `'react-native upgrade'`. When it asks me if I want to replace `AppDelegate.m` and `project.pbxproj` files I say yes.

8) Back in xCode I clean my build but still have the error from step 6 importing `<React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>`

Comment: I just converted my normal react-native project to cocoapods and it worked perfectly fine. Just had to reset the simulator to avoid some exception. Other than that didn't face any problem.

Answer (score 11):

I just make whole process with start from clean Xcode project. Usually I simple create RN application, eject and then translate to cocoapods ios part.
It largely based on RN docs: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.51/integration-with-existing-apps.html

So environment: macOS Sierra, Xcode 9.2, RN 0.51.0

Project name: MyApp

## Prepare

- Create new Xcode project, from 'Single View App' template, product name "MyApp", language Objective-C
- Run, see it works
- `cd MyApp`, `mkdir ios`, `mv MyApp* ios` (move all ios related files to ios subfolder)

## Install npm dependencies

Create `package.json` in root folder of you project (very basic)

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.0.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Run `npm install`

## Seup cocoapods

- `cd ios`
- `pod init` (generate Podfile)
- declare react dependencies in Podfile in MyApp target

```rb
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'DevSupport',
  ]
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
pod 'GLog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

You can add/remove React subspecs to include/remove RN functionality, this is hard process because RN components not fully independant.

- `pod install` (integrate pods into project, will create MyApp.xcworkspace, it should be used to compile application)
- `open MyApp.xcworkspace`, build & run, app should still work

## Embed RN Root View

Replace you AppDelegate.m with this snippet:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#if RCT_DEV
#import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  RCTBundleURLProvider* provider = [RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings];
  NSURL* jsCodeLocation = [provider jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleProvider:nil launchOptions:launchOptions];
#if RCT_DEV
  [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
#endif
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"MyApp" initialProperties:@{}];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

- Add ATS exception to Info.plist (or MyApp will be unable to connect to packager server with http)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

- Compile & run in Simulator, you should see red screen with message "No bundle URL present." (it is because no packager server running & no compiled jsbundle exists)

## Javascript part

Create `MyApp/index.js` with this code (it is from RN template):

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App);
```

Create `MyApp/App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

- start packager `npm start` from root project folder (`MyApp`)
- run app from xcode, you should see loading indicator and then RN rendered screen with "Welcome to React Native!"

## Packager

- You also should add packager build step to embed compiled js to app bundle `main.jsbundle` so it can be run without packager dev server.

Add script step to MyApp target's Build phases with this content:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

This steps works for me.