# [iOS][v0.44] Unable to archive - 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found in appDelegate.m

Tags: ios, reactjs, archive

'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found in appDelegate.m while trying to archive. Works like a charm in simulator as well as ios device in both debug and release mode. Already tried all the changes needed for RN >0.4.0.

Tried solutions suggested on #11813 (comment)
Removed parallelize build, added react to build targets before the app
Changed optimization level to none.
But nothing works

React Native version: 0.44.0
Platform: IOS
Development Operating System: macOS
Build tools: Xcode 8.3.2

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible duplicate of these questions, please try one of these solutions [rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368211/rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m), [react-native-0-40-0-rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704534/react-native-0-40-0-rctbundleurlprovider-h-file-not-found-appdelegate-m)